# GAE mapreduce and missing properties

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I've checked out mapreduce library for Python version of GAE today, and I can't seem to wrap my brain around it. I'm trying to iterate over datastore entities with missing properties, and add them. One of the properties has a default value, but other doesn't. The property that doesn't have the default value is calculated from another property (md5 sum of the email address which doubles as username).

Here's the code:

```
def user_schema(entity):
    entity.profile_id = hashlib.md5(string.strip(entity.username)).hexdigest()
    entity.verified = False
    operation.db.Put(entity)
```

When I run this, I get BadValueError for profile_id property because it's missing in all entities. I'm assuming this is happening even before mapreduce runs user_schema. How do I go about adding missing properties to entities?

Comment: sounds like the property DOES exist but as a previous type? Did you declare your property id previously? can you show the actual error/stacktrace, and how you have defined the properties on the Entity

Comment: Also, you don't need to checkout mapreduce. It's built into the SDK. In your app.yaml file,add: - url: /mapreduce(/.*)?\n
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py\n
  login: admin

Comment: @Chris: Property doesn't exist. I've used the datastore viewer to make sure. Anyhow, I've gotten around this issue by creating a copy of the model class and removing the required argument from the property in question. This did the trick.

Comment: @seedplane: I wasn't aware of that. The mapreduce documentation mentioned I had to check it out, so I just followed suit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've added a new property and set it as required, but not supplied a default, loading existing entities will cause the exception you're seeing, because the entities are missing a required property. You need to start by adding the property without the `required` flag, run the mapreduce to update old entities, and only then set the `required` flag to True.